# Reverting part of code of one file using GIT

Tags: git, github

I am working on a Python script. I am frequently committing changes to my Git / GitHub repository. Now, I am facing the situation that I need to revert some parts of my file. I introduced these changes some commits ago.

What's the best way to revert part of the code of one particular file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for a *best* way; there is not necessarily a best way.  There are many ways to accomplish your goal, though.

First, remember that what Git stores, in the level at which you use it, is *commits*.  Each commit holds a full and complete snapshot of *all* of your files.  When you use `git checkout` (or in Git 2.23 or later, `git switch`), you usually do this by selecting some *commit* (often, using a branch name).  That extracts *that* snapshot of all of your files.  You can now work with *that version* of *every* file.

What this means is that it is trivially easy to switch to a past version, but only if you want *every* file to come from that past version.  You would first select the particular commit you want—perhaps by running `git log` and looking at each commit until you find the one you want—then use its unique hash ID to check it out:

```
git checkout a123456
```

or:

```
git switch a123456
```

assuming the abbreviated commit hash is `a123456`.  (If you are using the mouse to cut and paste the hash ID, just grab and past the whole thing.)  This basically takes you "back in time" to that particular commit.  To return to the "current time" you just go back to your branch-tip commit, with `git checkout master` or `git switch feature` or whatever (again, using `git switch` if you are on Git 2.23 or later, or `git checkout` if an older Git, or you just prefer to stick with the older command).

But this is not what you want.  That would take *all* your files back in time to that version.  You only want to take *part of one file* back to that version.  So now you have a lot of options.  One may be the best for you.

In the next few sections, remember: **Every commit has a full and complete snapshot of all of your files.  Git provides *tools* for working with these snapshots.**  Some jobs are best done with some particular tools, and sometimes you can abuse a tool to good effect—e.g., using a flat-bladed screwdriver as a chisel—but the *right* tool will make it easier.

#### Consider using `git revert`

The `git revert` command essentially<sup>1</sup> compares a commit with its immediate parent commit, figures out what *changed*, and *un-does* that change.  Since you have been making many small commits, perhaps the bit of code you want to change *back* is the *only* thing you changed, if you compare the commit where you change that section of code, vs the commit before that point.

If so, `git revert <hash>` will undo that one change, making a new commit from the result.  You'll have exactly what you want, with one simple Git command.

If the change that you *committed* is bigger than the reversal that you *want*, you may still be able to use `git revert`.  Using `git revert -n`, Git will apply every "undo" to every file that was changed in that commit, but won't actually *commit* the undo.  You can then fix up anything you like, including using `git checkout HEAD -- path` to undo the undoing to any particular file.<sup>2</sup>  This is obviously more work than one revert that does everything, but might still be a useful way to employ the "back out a commit" tool.

---

<sup>1</sup>I say *essentially* because, internally, Git uses its *merge engine* to do the reversion work.  This means you can get *merge conflicts* when you do a revert.  If you do get one, and don't want to deal with it, you can use `git revert --abort` to undo the attempt to revert, and put everything back the way it was when you started.

Note that for `git revert --abort` to work, you need to *start* the revert with a "clean" setup.  However, plain `git revert` demands this anyway.  On the other hand, `git revert -n` doesn't, so be careful when using `git revert -n` to start with a clean setup—one where `git status` says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

<sup>2</sup>In Git 2.23 and later, you can use `git restore` for this, if you prefer.  The `git checkout HEAD --` method still works, though.

---

#### Consider using `git checkout -p`

If you've found a snapshot—*any* snapshot—that has the version of the code that you want, you can run:

```
git checkout -p <hash> -- <path>
```

to have Git *compare* the version of the file named *`path`* to the version of the file in the snapshot identified by *`hash`*.  That is, `git checkout -p` extracts the committed version of the file to a temporary area, then runs `git diff` to compare the temporary copy vs the copy you have in your regular work-tree area.  Then, for each change that this `git diff` shows, Git will offer to make the work-tree copy look like the committed copy.

You can now tell Git to take only the diff-hunks (parts of changes) that you want, and not the other parts.  Note that this process is very interactive: it tends to require a lot of human time.

#### Consider using `git show`

Again, each commit holds a full snapshot of all files.  But what if you just want to *look at*—and maybe save in some other file—the contents of *one* file from one particular commit?  The `git show` command can do this:

```
git show <hash>:<path>
```

displays, as shown through your pager, the committed copy of the file named *`path`* as it appears in the commit identified by *`hash`*.  You can use your shell's redirection operation:

```
git show <hash>:path/to/file.ext > path/to/file.ext.old
```

to dump the entire contents to a file.  Note that if you're in a subdirectory, such as `path/to`, you might want either:

```
git show <hash>:path/to/file.ext > file.ext.old
```

or:

```
git show <hash>:./file.ext > file.ext.old
```

as a shorter way to get this done (using the full path requires `cd`-ing to the top level of your repository first).

Now you have that particular version of the file, and can use any tool you like—such as your everyday file-editor—on both the current and old versions of the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer. I took the `git checkout -p` route. It enabled me to only revert some lines of a previous commit. For reference, to stage the change of each hunk, see the patch option at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add